# Python number rounding depends on the number

Tags: python, rounding

In python, I am using rounding to 1 decimal. But If a number is 0.03 or 0.005, then It should show until the last number in the decimal places.

```
def calculate_total(number):
   # some number calcualtions
   number = round(number, 1)
   print(number)
   

calculate_total(66.36) # 66.4
calculate_total(3.34) # 3.3
calculate_total(3.34) # 3.3
calculate_total(0.03) # 0.0 (But it should show 0.03)
calculate_total(0.0364) # 0.0 (But it should show 0.04)
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are rounding the float to one decimal place in `z = 0.03` and `z = 0.0364`

Just change `print(round(z, 1))` to `print(round(z, 2))` ; this will change the decimal place from 1 to 2 and it will produce your required output.

Comment: My early question was misleading. Sorry. I updated my question now.

Comment: Still the answer of the question remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type of code, providing your own condition.

In the following code, a rounding place is different depending on whether `z` variable is one of the value of (`0.03`, `0.005`) or not.

```
z = 66.36
result = round(z, 2)

l = (0.03, 0.005)
if result in l:
    print(round(result, 1))
else:
    print(round(result, 2))
```